# What is the correct verb for attending a conference call?

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality

I was invited to a conference call on Skype (it's a popular online conference call application, for those who aren't familiar). I texted a colleague who was also invited. I asked her, "Will you be attending the call?"

It occurred to me that "attending" would be correct for a face to face meeting, such as "Will you be attending the meeting?" or the more casual "Are you going to the meeting?" But it occurred to me that the word might not be precise. "Will you be joining the call?" is probably closer, as in "Bob just joined the call". But that still doesn't sound right. Is there a better word for attend when referring to an online call that no one has to leave their desk to be present at?

Comment: Related : [In a (conference) call or on a call ?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16504/in-a-call-versus-on-a-call).

Comment: Not that I post for the sake of getting upvotes or anything, but I just earned the "Famous Question" badge for this question. So, I have 10,000 views and one - just ONE - upvote for this extremely popular question. That should be a badge in itself.

Comment: And now I get downvotes to reduce it to zero. Awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A conference call is one where there are more than two interlocutors.

One does not attend a call (telephone). One can participate in a conference call. One can take part in a conference call. One can "be on a conference call".

- Will you **participate i**n the CC?
- Will you **be on** the CC?
- Will you **take part in** the CC?
- Will you be joining the CC?

Comment: I’ve heard all of above and you could add : will you **join** the CC ?

Comment: @k1eran Oh for pete's sake. I tried to upvote you and got confused and hit flag also, and you don't get a second chance at it. What a pain. Sorry about that.

Comment: no problem at all !

Comment: I think you are picking up what I am putting down. When trying to decide what word to use, I rely on what my ear tells me sounds right. "take part" is what sounds best to my ear. I guess I was looking for a one word answer, because I prefer one word to two when possible. Joining only seems to fit when describing what someone has DONE, not something you ASK someone to do. I can't quite explain why that is.

Comment: @CigarDoug  Sure, I agree: what sounds best. take part is participate, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

**"Will you be attending the skype call?"**

> And as Microsoft notes, meeting attendees do not need a Skype account
>   to **attend a Skype Call**: They can simply use Skype for Web instead.
>   [thurrot.com](https://www.thurrott.com/mobile/63901/outlook-for-android-ios-is-updated-with-skype-call-scheduling-and-more)

and

> It would be unprofessional and distracting **to attend a skype call** from
>   a coffee shop surrounded by loud neighbors, or a with a frappuccino. 
>   [theyogimovement.com](http://www.theyogimovement.com/get-out-of-rut-when-busy-and-back-to-your-old-self/)

support the use of to attend to such virtual calls/conferences.  In addition @Lambie's suggestions are nice too!

Comment: Thanks for that. I simply cannot get my head around, attend a call. It's attend a meeting virtually via a call. :)

Comment: Microsoft is trying to pitch Skype as an event, not as an instrument. I find it a very dishonest use of language.

Comment: Google created a product and made it a verb. Microsoft takes verbs and turns them into products. They... excel at doing that.

Comment: @KarlG  That's an excellent point. They sure do twist it up. [variation on mix it up, ha ha]