# How do I ask permission to override a course?

Tags: politeness, email

I need override for a course I want to take next semester. Instructor has asked to email him asking permission.

What should I write in the email?

> Respected sir/madam,
>
> I need prerequisite override for FOO101 Bar Spam course.
>
> WHAT SHOULD I WRITE HERE?
>
> Thank you!
>
> Sincerely,
>
> James Bond

Note: I was going to say "Please do the needful". [But its not recommended](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/115865/what-is-the-usual-form-of-please-do-the-needful).

Comment: First, "override" is a noun, not a verb. You don't want to override the course; you want an override slip/chop/form from the professor to allow you to take the course. This is a Permission, whether it's formally called that or not. So forget the bureaucratic terminology; you are asking a professor to permit you to take their class. Why should they permit you? Convince them.

Comment: Situation is little different here. Its not that me or other students don't have prerequisites. There is some problem with registration website. I don't have to convince the professor. I just need one last sentence in the email message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Dear Dr. Takahashi,
>
> I respectfully request that you initiate an override so that I may be registered to take your course, Foo Bar Spam [IDxxx]. My name is James
>   Bond and my student ID is 007.
>
> Cordially yours,

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the trick.

> Dear Professor X,
>
> I would like to request permission to enroll in your FOO101 Bar Spam course.
>
> *[insert here some convincing reasons for the professor to allow you to take the class]*
>
> Thank you.
>
> Sincerely,
>
> James Bond
> (Student no. 45826640A)